Can Spark SQL utilize previous results
I am curious if Spark can utilize previous results to help execution, for the example below:
Inside same session, I first create a view1 with some contents. Because there is no action, nothing is triggered. I then create view2 with df=sqlContext.sql("select * from view1 where col=something"), df.createOrReplaceTempView("view2"). Still nothing is triggered since no action.
Then I run: sqlContext.sql("select * from view1 limit 1000").collect(). This will trigger action and get results.
Now I want to run sqlContext.sql("select * from view2 limit 1000").collect().
My question is, will Spark internally optimize its execution for the 2nd query (1000 rows from view2) by using the results from 1st query (1000 rows from view1)? In theory, part of the results for 2nd query can be retrieved from 1st query, but IDK if Spark is really so intelligent.
Background: I am triaging the performance of Livy for interactive query.
Thanks.
I successfully run Livy.

yes it will use view1 to calculate view2. You can test this by not creating view1 it will throw error in runtime that view1 is not found

Spark does not automatically store the results of previous actions.
In the example you gave, Spark will not automatically use the result of the first query (select * from view1 limit 1000) to optimize the second query (select * from view2 limit 1000) because the result of the first query has not been persisted, and there is no indication that view2 relies on a subset of the data fetched by the first query.
If you want Spark to reuse the results from the first query, you should cache view1 before running the action.
